# Publish a COVID-19 paper post-COVID

Tags: graduate-school, research-undergraduate, covid-19

We did a study under a grant to investigate the effects of COVID-19 on Medical Education. We however had some few corrections and ended up not publishing. Is it reasonable to start publishing efforts now considering we did the study in 2020 and we`re already post'-COVID?

Comment: Does the paper contain study in 2021 and 2022 ?

Comment: We are very definitely not post-covid.

Comment: We may be pre- the next Covid wave. And we are probably pre-whatever other bad illness will appear. I suspect that the effects of Covid on medical education would apply to other highly infectious and possibly lethal infections as well.

Answer (score 6):

Of course it is reasonable to publish something about COVID-19 despite  the peak crisis of the pandemic having declined ... just as it is reasonable and useful to publish about the effects of

- the [Fukushima Daiichi disaster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fukushima_Daiichi_nuclear_disaster_casualties)
- the [2004 Indian Ocean earthquake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2004_Indian_Ocean_earthquake_and_tsunami)

or

- the [Great Influenza Pandemic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanish_flu)

even though they too are now over. Indeed, it is reasonable to expect that the publications that have already appeared regarding [COVID-19](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COVID-19_pandemic) will represent only a small fraction of the papers that will eventually be published. Research into a phenomenon or event, does not become irrelevant simply because the event has passed.

Comment: Thank yoyu..I will consult my Professor to see how i can jump start the whole thing